# How do I play an MP3 file and detect swipes at the same time?

Tags: android

In the same Activity, I would like to play an MP3 file. And while the MP3 file is playing,
I would like to be able to detect swipes.

I have the code to detect swipes ([source here](http://android-journey.blogspot.ca/2010/01/android-gestures.html)), but I am still figuring out how to detect swipes while an audio file is playing. How can I do this?

Comment: It should be no different. If you're using SoundPool or MediaPlayer to play your audio it's going to be running on another thread anyway (it's not going to block your UI).

Answer (score 1):

Start a separate thread for your music so that it doesn't affect the other processes.